# Why does glossaries-extra not show the long form of an abbreviation on first use?

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, glossaries-extra

I have a problem with using `glossaries-extra`, because it doesn't show the full form of my abbreviations upon first use within the document. A minimum working example:

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{siunitx}    \sisetup{detect-all}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nopostdot, toc, nogroupskip, nomain, indexonlyfirst, acronym, symbols, style=long4col, stylemods={longextra}]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{eu}{EU}{European Union}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\gls{eu}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\end{document}
```

This makes the abbrevation **EU** show up like **EU** in the document, whereas I'd expect it to show as **European Union (EU)** and as **EU** only on second usage.

When changing to the `glossaries` package, I *do* get this behaviour.

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{siunitx}    \sisetup{detect-all}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nopostdot, toc, nogroupskip, nomain, indexonlyfirst, acronym, symbols, style=long4col]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{eu}{EU}{European Union}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\gls{eu}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\end{document}
```

An obvious solution would be to switch to the glossaries package, which I'd do if I weren't using the stylemods of the `glossaries-extra` package.

It's such a simple MWE, that I'm probably going to feel very stupid once I see my mistake, but isn't this default behaviour difference of `glossaries` and `glossaries-extra` very confusing? Or is it some of my loaded packages clashing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick search in the manual suggests that you need to add `\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{siunitx}    \sisetup{detect-all}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nopostdot, toc, nogroupskip, nomain, indexonlyfirst, acronym, symbols, style=long4col, stylemods={longextra}]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}% <<<<<<

\newacronym{eu}{EU}{European Union}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\gls{eu}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else encounters this issue, another possible reason is that `\newacronym` is before `\setabbreviationstyle`, in which case everything seems to work fine except precisely for the fact that the first `\gls` appears in abbreviated form only.

**Putting the `\newacronym` after `\setabbreviationstyle` fixed it for me**.